# Magento Homepage HTML layout issue with Jquery Slider - Code/Pictures Within

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento, layout

Thank you for taking the time to read this. The easiest way to describe the problem is to see it http://foscam-uk.com/index.php  (note this is running the correct styles.css and not the theme316 as per later on this post)

As you can see the featured products and bestsellers blocks have been moved to the far right of the page, when they should look like this image with the jQuery Slider above them : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBjG.jpg

I believe there is something in the style.css which can be found here http://foscam-uk.com/skin/frontend/default/mt_segina/css/styles.css as I had to copy parts from a previous style css which is from here http://foscam-uk.com/skin/frontend/default/theme316/css/styles.css

Also the code for the jQuery can be found here : http://foscam-uk.com/widget  (note this is running from the original theme316 css file).

I know this is a bit of a long post, thank you very much in advance to everyone who takes the time to look at this.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming you mean the blocks have moved to the far *left* of the page?

What I can see happening is you have a `float:left` on `div.col-main` which is causing it to stick to the left. Also the width you have set for this div *680px* is too small for both the best sellers and featured products to fit. Try upping your width to match the jQuery slider above it as well as setting an auto margin to horizontally centre it. Eg:

```
.col-main {
    width: 954px;
    padding: 0 0 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or you can make it so that `div.col-main` is nested inside of the `div.wrapper` and not bother adding a custom width.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Look like there're conflicts between jQuery and Prototype. How did you call jQuery in your site? Please see this blog for more information:
http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/using-jquery-magento

or
http://css-tricks.com/using-jquery-in-magneto/

There're many articles about using jQuery in magento.